# How to get Foreign Key ID to show two models in DetailView?

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-views

I've created these two models: "Property" and "Bedroom". I've created a Class Based View, DetailView to show the details from Property, but now I need to show not only the property details but also the bedroom details.

```
# models.py
class Property(models.Model):
    property_reference = models.CharField(db_column='Property_Reference', max_length=10)  # Field name made lowercase.
    address = models.CharField(db_column='Address', max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    post_code = models.CharField(db_column='Post_Code', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    type = models.CharField(db_column='Type', max_length=25, blank=True, null=True, choices=HOUSE_TYPE_CHOICES)  # Field name made lowercase.
    bedrooms = models.IntegerField(db_column='Bedrooms', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    bathrooms = models.IntegerField(db_column='Bathrooms', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    usual_cleaning_requirements = models.CharField(db_column='Usual_Cleaning_Requirements', max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    notes = models.CharField(db_column='Notes', max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    feature_image = models.ImageField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Property'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.property_reference

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("properties:property_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})


class Bedroom(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(db_column='Type', choices=BEDROOM_TYPE_CHOICES, max_length=50)
    bed_dimensions = models.CharField(db_column='Bed_Dimension', choices=BED_DIMENSION_CHOICES, max_length=30)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    ensuite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    notes = models.CharField(db_column='Notes', max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bedroom')
```

And I've created this view:

```
class PropertyDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'properties/property-detail.html'
    model = Property

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['bedrooms'] = Bedroom.objects.get(property = property.property_id)
        return context
```

I must be doing something wrong cause I'm still learning, could you please help me?

Comment: You don't need that `get_context_data` method at all. In the template, you can simply iterate through `property.bedroom.all`.

Comment: You should tell us what's going wrong. Do you see an error? Something else? @DanielRoseman is correct, but your question is incomplete.  Also when fetching multiple objects using the model manager (`Bedroom.objects`), you can't use `get()` (that's for one single object) but you should use `filter()`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you so much for the help! I'll post an answer whit what I've came up with your help.

Comment: @dirkgroten I'll pay attention to those things on my next questions. I was getting property_id does not exist. Thank you for your help. I solved my problem with Daniel Roseman help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question with the help of @Daniel Roseman. It is working now.

I've deleted the get_context_data() on PropertyDetailView

```
#views.py

class PropertyDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'properties/property-detail.html'
    model = Property
```

I've iterated with a for loop on my property-detail.html

```
    # property-details.html
<tbody>
       {% for bedroom in property.bedroom.all %}
         <tr>
            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">{{ bedroom.type }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ bedroom.bed_dimensions }}</td>
            <td><span class="text-muted"> {{ bedroom.ensuite }}</span> </td>
            <td>{{ bedroom.notes }}</td>
         </tr>
       {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```